# Are questions about how the number and types of movie theaters change over time on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've just posted [Are there “fewer independent theaters than ever”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/104950/45856) in the main site and I'm not sure if a question about data on the number of independent theaters (US or world-wide) is on-topic here.

I noticed that there is no [theaters](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theaters) tag, but someone added the [distribution](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution) tag which has almost 150 questions.

Is this question on-topic? If there's an issue, can it be improved?

My question is not about the Martin Scorsese opinion piece in the New York Times, but I'm assuming he has some credibility in the industry so I'm premising my question on his authority.

Comment: I don't see why it would not be on topic.

Answer (score 6):

### My inclination is that this **IS** on-topic.

Certainly it fits onto the category of:

> Questions relating to the film and TV industry

...as stated in our help guide.

Nor can I find a reason that would "fit" for closing it as "off-topic".